# grub - Keyboard stuck in GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard, windows-7

I have dual booted Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. I have Intel DH67BL motherboard which does not support PS/2 keyboard,mouse and am using Logitech K120 USB 2.0 keyboard.
I have set GRUB to load Windows 7 by default within 10 seconds. But most of the (7/10)time when GRUB loads the keyboard is stuck. I can see the time running out in GRUB. But my keyboard gets stuck in GRUB menu. None of the key work(not even NumLock key).
But the keyboard works perfectly in BIOS, Windows Bootloader and all other boot programs. So what I am thinking is that, the problem is in GRUB. After searching a lot, here is list what I have tried:
1) Set USB Legacy Support Enable in BIOS 
2) Changed USB port of keyboard

None of above solution work
Is there any alternative to GRUB which support dual boot. I have heard about UEFI bootloaders. Is it also a bootloader like GRUB? If yes how can I use it?
I am tired of this problem. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Did you tried grub (not grub2, but the 'legacy' one)?

Comment: @nsilent22 No, i have not. How can I replace grub2 with it?

Comment: I believe you have to `sudo apt-get install grub`. Then grub2 will be removed and legacy grub installed. Of course make sure you have some alternate boot method at hand (e.g. live cd) in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after trying different solutions my problem got solved.
I replaced GRUB2 with BURG. See [here](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-burg-boot-loader-in-ubuntu-1304-and-linuxmint/) for install instructions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but solved it by disabling "PS/2 Keyboard/Mouse Emulation" option in my BIOS. By default it was set to "Always". There was another possible setting, "Auto" that didn't work either.